# cannot get output from php class from using drupal framework

Tags: php, drupal

I wrote a simple class using drupal framework it doesn't return any output from with in the class. here is the code.

```
class abc {
  private $abc = "classs";

  public function output(){
     return $this->abc;
   }
}

echo df= new abc();
if ($df){
  echo "instantiated"; // I wrote this to verify whether $db is instantiating the class or not
}

$df->output();

if($df->output())
{
  echo "<br /> <br /> damm drupal"; // simply to verify
}

error_reporting(E_ALL); // no errors
```

here is the output

```
instantiated 

damm drupal
```

but I don't see the output from the method output in the class "abc".

Is it something to do in bootstrap.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to echo the output!

So write this:

```
echo $df->output();
```